# compare string contents in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, comparison

I have a 2 lists of strings
eg:

```
listx = ["name","age","rank"]
input = ["name","age"]
```

How can I compare the two lists to check whether the `listx` contains `"name"` & `"age"` given in `input`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this homework? :)

You need to create one or two recursive functions to walk through both lists, and search for every string in the input.

Or, you could look up some good functions in the Prelude that helps here.

Comment: yea, im new to haskell. I tried it out but I get an error.

inputIndex :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
inputIndex [] _ = []
inputIndex listx input = [x `elem` listx |x <- input]

error:
- Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : inputIndex
*** Type           : [String] -> [String] -> [a]
*** Does not match : [String] -> [String] -> Bool

Comment: @dlna: your function is returning a list of Bools, one for each x. Whereas you just want one Bool, which is the logical and of all of them, so one thing you could do is "inputIndex listx input = and [x `elem` listx |x <- input]"

Comment: Yup. There you are. 'and' is what you need to reduce [Bool] -> Bool.

Answer (score 6):

B is a subset of A iff B \ A is empty

so another way to do it is

```
import Data.List ((\\))
null (input \\ listx)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
all (flip elem listx) input
```

comes to mind. No idea how efficient it is though...

Comment: you can also write it as "all (`elem` listx) input". @dlna: basically it expands to "all (\x -> x `elem` listx) input", which ensures that for every element of input, that it is an element of listx

Answer (score 4):

One more way.

```
import Data.Set
(fromList input) `isSubsetOf` (fromList listX)
```