# compare lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, comparison, flip

I've been trying to compare two lists in Haskell and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849659/compare-string-contents-in-haskell).

I wonder how `all (flip elem listx) input` works, especially for the role `flip` plays here.

When I take out `flip` it won't work anymore.

Comment: Note: I suspect this would be idiomatically written: ``all (`elem` listx) input``.  If you know about backticks and operator sections this should make sense.

Comment: But why elem is an infix here?

Comment: Any function with at least 2 arguments can be used in infix form. And because `e ´elem´ list` just reads better than `elem e list` many prefer it this way.

Comment: but the two arguments are listx and input? so isn't it a prefix notation here?

Comment: `input` isn't an argument to `elem`, quite. Read left to right. `all` takes two arguments, a function and a list, and returns true if the function is true for everything in the list. The arguments to elem are listx and one element at a time from input.

Comment: The complexity of your solution is O(n²), wouldn't something like `sort listx == sort input` be preferrable, for O(n log n) complexity?

Comment: @Zopa, yeah, but what's puzzled me is whether it's a infix notation here where a backtick is needed

Comment: @valderman, thx for advice! I'm new to Haskell and functional programming so efficiency is not my concern for the current

Answer (score 9):

1. `flip elem listx` is equivalent to `(flip elem) listx`.
2. `(flip elem)` is the same as `elem`, but with the arguments in opposite order. This is what `flip` does.
3. `elem` is a function that takes an element and a list, and checks whether the element belongs to the list.
4. So `flip elem` is a function that that takes a list and an element, and checks whether the element belongs to the list.
5. Therefore `flip elem listx` is a function that that takes an element, and checks whether the element belongs to `listx`.
6. Now `all` takes a predicate and a list, and checks whether all elements of the list satisfy the predicate.
7. `all (flip elem listx)` take a list, and checks whether all elements of the list satisfy `flip elem listx`. That is, whether they all belong to `listx`.
8. `all (flip elem listx) input` checks whether all elements of `input` belong to `listx`.
9. Q.E.D.

Comment: @n.m. I found the type of flip on [Hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:flip)`flip :: (a->b->c)->b->a->c`which makes me to believe it is `a elem listx` supposing a is an element of input. It makes sense now why flip is needed here and I have to use backtick without it